# Небольшие фризы в игре

Tags: unity3d

При запуске игры наблюдаются небольшие фризы, на сцене довольно много объектов

Статистика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Profiler:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И половина из этих объектов создаются и удаляются на сцене!

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Что значит пул?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по скриншоту из профилировщика у вас все время уходит на **V-Sync**

Управлять этим можно вот тут, попробуйте отключить вертикальную синхронизацию:

```
Edit->Project Settings->Quality->VSync Count.
```

> [Вертикальная синхронизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) (V-Sync) - синхронизация кадровой частоты в компьютерной игре с частотой вертикальной развёртки монитора. При этом максимальный FPS с вертикальной синхронизацией приравнивается к частоте обновления монитора.

---

Так же попробуйте использовать [пул объектов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB)

Реализация для Unity есть в AssetStore - [LeanPool](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/lean-pool-35666)

А вообще-то подход довольно прост, можете и сами реализовать нечто подобное, смысл - не порождать новые объекты, а брать их из пула, и не уничтожать их, а складывать обратно в пул, а порождать только тогда, когда они в пуле закончились (тут может быть любая другая логика, обрабатывающая переполнение).

Comment: Круто! Сейчас проверю и если фризы пропадут поставлю "Верный ответ"

Comment: @AimonZ. не факт что фризы пропадут, но ради интереса прикрепите скрин из профилировщика после применения изменений

Comment: Стало только хуже

Comment: Посмотрите тогда вот сюда: Edit->Project Settings->Quality->VSync Count. попробуйте отключить vsync

Comment: Помогло! Вы можете оформить как ответ чтобы я вам поставил как правильный. И да что даёт этот VSync Count

Comment: @AimonZ. я дополню этот ответ, т.к. Lean pool Тоже мог помочь в случае с тоннами объектов

Comment: @Aimon Z. изменил ответ